# Increase limit from 1000?

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

When I do a search like so

```
my $mesg = $ldap->search(
  base   => "OU=test,DC=example,DC=com",
  scope  => 'one',
  filter => '(objectClass=organizationalPerson)',
  attrs  => ['distinguishedName', 'displayName', 'sAMAccountName', 'employeeID'],
);
```

I only get 1000 entries, where I would expect ~20000.

Is it possible to increase this limit in my Perl script, or does it have to be changed on the server?

Comment: Information about what modules are in play would make this question more useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to use paged search like so

```
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAP::Control::Paged;
use Net::LDAP::Constant qw( LDAP_CONTROL_PAGED );

my $page = Net::LDAP::Control::Paged->new(size => 999);
my $cookie;

while (1) {
    $mesg = $ldap->search(
    base    => "OU=test,DC=example,DC=com",
    scope   => 'one',
    filter  => '(objectClass=organizationalPerson)',
    attrs   => ['distinguishedName', 'displayName', 'sAMAccountName', 'employeeID'],
    control => [$page]
    );

    $mesg->code && die "Error on search: $@ : " . $mesg->error;
    while (my $adentry = $mesg->pop_entry()) {

    # process $adentry
    }

    my ($resp) = $mesg->control(LDAP_CONTROL_PAGED) or last;
    $cookie    = $resp->cookie or last;
    # Paging Control
    $page->cookie($cookie);
}

if ($cookie) {
    print "abnormal exit\n";
    # Abnormal exit, so let the server know we do not want any more
    $page->cookie($cookie);
    $page->size(0);
    $ldap->search(control => [$page]);
}
```

Comment: Nice to ask yourself questions ;o) . Just one thing. Be careful It's not "normal" to search so much items in a directory. A Directory **IS NOT A DATABASE** . Performances may get bad. Reserve this way of programming for provisionning purpose.

Answer (score 3):

AD by default set the maximum page size to 1000. The client will receive the first 1000 result and also an receive an error "Size Limit Exceeded".

To avoid this the client has to use paged control, if the paged control is used the server will not return error but instead it will send a cookie (a byte) to indicate there is some more result available. If there is no cookie available which means no more result. So you can continue looping for the result until cookie is null.

You can also modify MaxPageSize in the server if you want, start ntdsutil and
type the following,

```
ldap policies 
connections 
connect to server servername.domain.name 
q 
set maxpagesize to 5000 
commit 
changes 
q 
q
```

This is mostly done if the client does not support paging and the client can not be modified.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify the module that you are using to ldap search. By the way 'sizelimit' key can be used to it but by default it is not limited. This can be a server side limit configuration.