# SizeLimit exceeded using Net::LDAP::Control::Paged

Tags: perl, active-directory, ldap

According to all the documentation I've read, the maximum size of a result set when querying Active Directory is 1000 records.  If you need more than 1000, you are told to use Net::LDAP::Control::Paged in order to page through and get more than 1000 records, which I have attempted to do.  For some reason, I am still only getting 1000 records back, despite using a paged control.  I am using the same code that others have claimed to be using successfully without any luck.  Am I missing something here?  Please note that I do not have administrative access to the AD servers, so changing the configuration is not an option for me.  I've pasted the relevant code below so you can point out whatever I might have done wrong.

```
#!perl -w

use strict;
use Net::LDAP;
use Net::LDAP::Control::Paged;
use Net::LDAP::Constant qw( LDAP_CONTROL_PAGED );

my $LDAPServer      = "<LDAP SERVER ADDRESS>";
my $base        = "<BASE DN>";
my $user                = "<LDAP USER>";
my $pass                = "<PASSWORD>";
my $page                = Net::LDAP::Control::Paged->new(size => 1000) or die $!;
my $errorConnectionStr  = "";
my $ldap;
my $mesg;
my $cookie;

$ldap = Net::LDAP->new($LDAPServer);
$mesg = $ldap->bind($user, password => $pass, version => 3);

open(OUT,">users.csv");
print OUT "sAMAccountName,sn,givenName\n";

my $filter = "(&(objectClass=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))(!(objectClass=computer)))";
my @attribs = ("sn", "givenName", "sAMAccountName", "distinguishedName");

my @args = (
        base    => $base,
        scope   => 'sub',
        filter  => $filter,
        attrs   => @attribs,
        pagesize => 1000,
        control => [$page]
);

while(1) {
    $mesg = $ldap->search(@args) or die $!;

    while (my $entry = $mesg->pop_entry()) {
        my $print = 1;

        my $dn = $entry->dn();
        my $uid = $entry->get_value('sAMAccountName');
        my $ln = $entry->get_value('sn');
        my $fn = $entry->get_value('givenName');

        if($dn =~ m/.*Resources.*/) {
            $print = 0;
        }

        if(defined($uid) && defined($ln) && defined($fn)) {
            if($print == 1) {
                print OUT "$uid,$ln,$fn\n";
            }
        }
    }

    my ($resp) = $mesg->control(LDAP_CONTROL_PAGED) or last;
    $cookie = $resp->cookie or last;
    $page->cookie($cookie);
}

if($cookie) {
    print "Abnormal exit\n";
    $page->cookie($cookie);
    $page->size(0);
    $ldap->search(@args);
}

close(OUT);
$ldap->unbind;
```

Comment: I believe this is already answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830860/increase-limit-from-1000).

Comment: @sferencik No, the code that I'm using in my example is using LDAP::Control::Paged as the page you linked explains in its answer.  The question you linked is asking how to return more than 1000 records, and the answer provided is to use the same control I'm trying to use that is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `attrs => \@attrs,` in `@args`. Without the backslash you're interpolating an odd number of elements (`'attrs'` plus the four elements of the array) and the search method doesn't see the `pagesize` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I just used it for the first time, and it works here.  My seach is pretty simple (show all objects in a container).  I'm listing 11.5k groups by grabbing them in 800-group pages.  My code is nearly identical to yours (it's a mixture of the example on the Net::LDAP::Control::Paged man page and yours), except I don't specify a page size in the search:

```
while (1) {
   my $mesg = $x->{ldap}->search(base => $x->{config}->{gbase},
                                scope => 'sub',
                              control => [$page],
                               filter => 'cn=*',
                                attrs => \@attrs,
   );
   die "LDAP error: server says ",$mesg->error,"\n" if $mesg->code;

   foreach my $entry ( $mesg->entries ) {
      my $cn   = $entry->get_value('cn');
      my $desc = $entry->get_value('description');
      print "$cn - $desc\n";
   }

   # Get cookie from paged control
   my($resp)  = $mesg->control( LDAP_CONTROL_PAGED )  or last;
   $cookie    = $resp->cookie or last;

   # Set cookie in paged control
   $page->cookie($cookie);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can't use a size of 1000 since it's the AD limit and hence doesn't page. Needs to be something less than that. Try 999 and be happy.

Comment: You're right. Windows server ldap is mean. breaking 1000 or 999 object seaarch is possible on modern ldap protocol, using paging facility. unfortunately I cannot change my vote, it is outdated.