# How to increase the sizelimit of LDAP?

Tags: ldap, redhat, openldap

My ldapsearch command is only returning a max of 500 entries, while I know I > have over 24,000 entries in the database. how can I increase the sizelimit, to display all my entries. Please Provided details steps

Comment: By editing the configuration. Off topic.

Comment: you can't from the clients side. You will have to use paged search or increase the sizelimit on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

as heiglandreas mentioned, this is a server side limit.

If you are using slapd.conf, this would be the sizelimit directive.

If you are using cn=config, this would be olcSizelimit attribute.

You can change it on the client side with -E pr=nnnn but only *up to* the server side limit.  Some language specific tools like Perl's Net::LDAP::Control::Paged ([SizeLimit exceeded using Net::LDAP::Control::Paged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309539/sizelimit-exceeded-using-netldapcontrolpaged)) can provide the tools to query in those languages.